# sed: How would I find a string that doesn't include a specific word?

Tags: sed

I want to update all the import statements without `legacy/` and add `legacy/` to them.

current:

```
import Page from 'ui/components/legacy/Page';
import Foobar from 'ui/components/Foobar';
```

expected result:

```
import Page from 'ui/components/legacy/Page';
import Foobar from 'ui/components/legacy/Foobar';
```

Using sed, how would I do a regex for finding all import statements with `components/(not legacy)` and replace them with `components/legacy`?

`find . -name '*.js' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "" "s/????/????/g"`

Comment: Sed has a logical NOT operator. You could build off of `/not legacy/! { }`.

Comment: Would you be able to show me a complete regex?

Answer (score 0):

You may use this `sed`:

```sh
sed -E '/^import / { /\/legacy\/[^/]+$/!s~/[^/]+$~/legacy&~;}' file

import Page from 'ui/components/legacy/Page';
import Foobar from 'ui/components/legacy/Foobar';
```

**Explanation:**

- `/^import /`: Only for lines starting with `import`
- `{`: Group start

  - `/\/legacy\/[^/]+$/!`: If we don't have `/legacy/` followed by 1+ non-`/` character in a line
  - `s~/[^/]+$~/legacy&~`: Insert `/legacy` before substring starting with last `/` in a line
- `}`: Group end

Combining with `find`:

```
find . -name '*.js' -exec sed -i -E '/^import /{ /\/legacy\/[^/]+$/!s~/[^/]+$~/legacy&~;}' {} +
```

Comment: Hi I would like to use it in a find and replace. How would I modify your regex to do that?

Comment: I have already includes complete `find` command in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up coming with the answer myself

`find . -name '*.js' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "" "/ui\/components\/legacy/! s/ui\/components/ui\/components\/legacy/"`